# How to write junits for custom spring batch reader

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-batch, spring-test

below is my custom Spring Batch Reader. I HAVE TO write junits that cover `setPreparedStatementSetter()` and `setRowMapper()` methods. No matter what I try, my unit test doesnt cover the code within those methods. Can someone please point me how to write junit for such anonymous methods. Thanks.

**PS**: I know junits are not meant to be written to test framework specific implementation methods, but I need this for my code coverage.

```
public class MyDataReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<ABC> {
    public MyReader(DataSource dataSource, String beginTime, String endTime) {
      setSql(QUERY);
      setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            // Set parameters on the SQL query
            ps.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(beginTime.trim()));
            ps.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(endTime.trim()));
        }
      });

    setDataSource(dataSource);
    setRowMapper((ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
      ABC abc = new ABC();
      abc.setDateTime(getLongOrNull("DT", rs));         
      abc.setStmt(getBooleanOrNull("SP", rs));

      return abc;
    });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class for your `RowMapper` and `PreparedStatementSetter` then unit test them. Here is an example for the row mapper:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class ABCRowMapper implements RowMapper<ABC> {

    @Override
    public ABC mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        ABC abc = new ABC();
        abc.setDateTime(rs.getLong("DT"));
        abc.setStmt(rs.getBoolean("SP"));

        return abc;
    }

}
```

And the corresponding test:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class ABCRowMapperTest {

    @Test
    public void testABCRowMapper() throws Exception {
        // given
        ABCRowMapper rowMapper = new ABCRowMapper();
        ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getLong("DT")).thenReturn(1L);
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getBoolean("SP")).thenReturn(true);

        // when
        ABC abc = rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, 1);

        // then
        Assert.assertNotNull(abc);
        Assert.assertEquals(abc.getDateTime(), 1L);
        Assert.assertTrue(abc.getStmt());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your response! I can try that, but I didn't want to refactor my code only for the purpose of code coverage.

Comment: You definitely should! Not for coverage, but to make sure your mapping logic works as expected.